# window function between program and math

Tags: fft, python, window-functions

I'm newbie on signal processing.
I know when we program python with window function. (just signal multiply with window)

According to Harris paper

[image]

[image]

I know we change w with different window(blackman).

However in python `fft(signal*window(blackman))`.

Is there still window(rectangular) function when we do signal capture(fft) in programming?

I mean that dft(signal * blackman * rectangular).

Comment: The rectangular window won't change anything if it has the same length as your signal, but if it had smaller length, then it will cause more spectral broadening and leakage (the multiplication of rectanglar and blackman window act as a new windowing function).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using a time limited sample of the waveform is the rectangular window that is referenced. Since the fft operates on a time limited sequence, it is mathematically identical to a infinitely long duration of that sequence multiplied the rectangular window.